# How to list the total number and specific details of registrants for each event

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

[t_event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWZNP.png)
[t_attendant & t_user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ5Qz.png)

Below shown are their respective tables i would like to know how do we get the list the total number and specific details of registrants for each event.

> 

```
include "database_conn.php";
$sqlRegisteredEvent = "SELECT 
                        Events.*,
                       COUNT(DISTINCT Registrants.regID) AS registrantCount
                        FROM t_events AS Events 
                        LEFT JOIN t_attendant AS Registrants 
                        ON (Registrants.eventID = Events.eventID)
                        GROUP BY 
                        Events.id";
$listAllEvent = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRegisteredEvent);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listAllEvent))
{
    $id = $row['regID'] ;
    $eName  = $row['eventName' ] ;
    $eUserName   = $row['firstName'];
    $eEmail = $row['email'] ;

    //start a row
    echo"<tr>";

    //output event name
    echo "<td>$eName</td>";

    //output user fist name
    echo "<td>$eUserName</td>";

    //output user email
    echo "<td>$eEmail</td>";

    //output registration ID
    echo "<td>$id</td>";

    echo"</tr>";

}
echo"</table>";
```

?>

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: use a select COUNT

Comment: Do not use images. Stack allows you to post code, you know

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN` and `COUNT`. This is a shot in the dark since your question is of poor quality.

```
SELECT 
    Events.*,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Registrants.regID) AS registrantCount
FROM t_events AS Events 
LEFT JOIN t_attendant AS Registrants 
    ON (Registrants.eventID = Events.eventID)
GROUP BY 
    Events.id
```